# How to plug-in this hard drive?

Tags: hard-drive, upgrade, sata, power-management, molex

I need to install this hard drive "WD800JD-60JRC0". It is Serial ATA. But what really confuses me is that it has molex connector. I think I can plug what I want: SATA power cable or Molex. But which one is better?

Comment: Just don't plug in both.

Comment: @MSalters I found that out the hard way on my first WD sata drive when they first came out, ouch!

Comment: @Moab  What happened?  I wouldn't've thought anything would since you'd have the same voltages coming in over both cables.

Comment: @Dan Neely, I had to rma the drive, it killed it. After reading the instructions is clearly stated not to do this :->

Comment: @Moab: Another risk is that your PSU has two separate 12V output rails, which you might cross-connect via the harddisk. It's not designed to handle those currents.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Older drives, especially during the transition between SATA and PATA had both connectors - that meant you could use a non sata PSU with a sata motherboard (or a non sata motherboard with a sata card). Use either one - the 3.5 v connector in sata is the only major difference electrically, and this isn't used in that drive.

Comment: AFAIK even on current generation SATA drives the 3.3V line is normally unused since the retail boxed versions of the drives typically still come with a molex-sata power adapter cable.

Comment: Thats true - though i admit that most drives i buy are simply wrapped in anti static bags, and never come with one of those. I assumed that by now, that sata capable PSUs would be common enough that that connector would be used.

Comment: The Samsung 830 SSD I bought a week ago came with the adapter cable; and if any drive category was going to be the first to drop it...  I suspect it comes down to drive electronics running on lower voltages anyway, and it just being simpler to run the +5/12v line into the DC Power converter.

Answer (score 5):

Either cable will work. It will simply depend what you have available.

Both Molex and SATA power cables will work. The basic difference between the two is the `Connector Type` - `Molex` is more generic and found on lower end PSU's, it is also a bulkier connector type.

[image: Molex vs SATA connectors]

Answer (score 0):

They both supply the power the drive needs; neither will do anything *more* than the other.

Comment: The SATA power cable is hot-pluggable, however.  Molex is not.